# Postgresql 13 Stored Procedure issue

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am new to postgresql. I am trying to load query output into a temp table and wanted to use that temp table further in the stored procedure. But it is not allowing to save the following script.

Kindly share some pointers. I am unable to get any reference from internet/google

It throws an error:
ERROR: relation "newtemptable" does not exist
LINE 7: select * from newtemptable
^

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_getworkflow()
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
CREATE TEMP TABLE newtemptable AS 
select "TXNID", "FILENAME"  from "oldtable" where "TXNID" = 'abc';
SELECT * FROM "newtemptable";
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Only a single sql statement is allowed in a SQL function/procedure. There are two in the example above. For multiple statements you need `plpgsql`.

Comment: Thanks @Stefanov.sm. I got it.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm That is not true. You can have multiple SQL statements, and the last will produce the function result.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, my mistake.